# Plotting Pandas' pivot_table from long data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, panel-data

I have a xls file with data organized in long format. I have four columns: the variable name, the country name, the year and the value.

After importing the data in Python with pandas.read_excel, I want to plot the time series of one variable for different countries. To do so, I create a pivot table that transforms the data in wide format. When I try to plot with matplotlib, I get an error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ZAF'
```

(where 'ZAF' is the label of one country)

What's the problem?

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_excel('raw_emissions_energy.xls','raw data', index_col = None, thousands='.',parse_cols="A,C,F,M")

data['Year'] = data['Year'].astype(str)
data['COU'] = data['COU'].astype(str)

# generate sub-datasets for specific VARs

data_CO2PROD = pd.pivot_table(data[(data['VAR']=='CO2_PBPROD')], index='COU', columns='Year')

plt.plot(data_CO2PROD)
```

The xls file with raw data looks like:
[raw data Excel view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1bom.png)

[image]

This is what I get from data_CO2PROD.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 105 entries, ARE to ZAF
Data columns (total 16 columns):
(Value, 1990)    104 non-null float64
(Value, 1995)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2000)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2001)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2002)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2003)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2004)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2005)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2006)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2007)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2008)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2009)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2010)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2011)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2012)    105 non-null float64
(Value, 2013)    105 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(16)
memory usage: 13.9+ KB
None
```

Comment: Is possible share your `xls`?

Comment: just added a screenshot at the end of the question

Comment: And where is value `ZAF`? Only in `COU` column?

Comment: yes, only in the COU column

Comment: I think problem is with `data_CO2PROD`. What is `data_CO2PROD.info()` ? I think there is `Multiindex` in columns.

Comment: see above at end of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need add parameter `values` to `pivot_table`:

```
data_CO2PROD = pd.pivot_table(data=data[(data['VAR']=='CC')], 
                              index='COU', 
                              columns='Year', 
                              values='Value')

data_CO2PROD.plot()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using data_CO2PROD.plot() instead of plt.plot(data_CO2PROD) allowed me to plot the data. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html.
Simple code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,4), columns=['VAR','COU','Year','VAL'])
data['VAR'] = ['CC','CC','KK']
data['COU'] =['ZAF','NL','DK']
data['Year']=['1987','1987','2006']
data['VAL'] = [32,33,35]

data['Year'] = data['Year'].astype(str)
data['COU'] = data['COU'].astype(str)

# generate sub-datasets for specific VARs

data_CO2PROD = pd.pivot_table(data=data[(data['VAR']=='CC')], index='COU',    columns='Year')
data_CO2PROD.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: How did you get the OPs data? Did you "OCR" it?

Comment: I tried, but I do not get any plot (but not even an error)

Comment: @ClaB, that's why you should always post your data sets in the TEXT/CSV form, but not as a picture - we can't test our solutions then...

Comment: I did not know how to do it!

Comment: You can [post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39561248/edit) your data into your question or upload your excel file somewhere and post a link in your question