# Pandas DataFrame plotting - Tick labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

this is a follow-up question on a piece of code I have [posted previously here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561248/python-plotting-pandas-pivot-table-from-long-data).

I am plotting a Dataframe object using `data_CO2_PBPROD.T.plot(marker='o', color='k', alpha=0.3, lw=2)` but I get on the x-axis double labels, as you can see in this picture
[image]

I tried to work on the set_major_formatter property of matplotlib.pyplot.axes() but then I get a separate graph with the correct tick labels - but no data displayed - along with the previous graph, unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the argument **xticks** to set the values of your axis as explained in the documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
xticks = [date for _ ,date in data_CO2_PBPROD.Column1]
```

Where **Column1** is the column of your DataFrame containing the tuples (Values, Year)

Then put the **xticks** as a parameter to your plot function :

```
data_CO2_PBPROD.T.plot(marker='o', xticks=xticks, color='k', alpha=0.3, lw=2)
```

Comment: with your suggestion I get an error at the .plot  line: "TypeError: unorderable types: numpy.ndarray() < str()" Notice that I replaced ".Column1" with ".columns"

Comment: and if I convert xticks into Integers, I get no error but the scale of the xaxis is completely wrong